# Using a macro in another macro and then undefining(#undef) the first macro c++

Tags: c++, c, c-preprocessor

The following code does not compile:

```
#define SOME_MACRO(x,y) x+y
#define ADD_ONE_TO(x) SOME_MACRO(x,1)
#undef SOME_MACRO

int main(){
    ADD_ONE_TO(1);
}
```

Is there any hack to either:

1. Prevent code duplication by having common functionality in SOME_MACRO and using it in other macros BUT undef`ing it to prevent its usage in common user-code.
2. Somehow making it so the ADD_ONE_TO macro just copy-pastes the macros it uses instead of referncing them.
3. Preventing user-code from accessing and using SOME_MACRO but allowing it to be used in other specific parts of code(other, select, macros)
4. Hide the implementation of macros by disallowing access(undef or otherwise) to the macros inside the macro which we want to hide the implementation of.

Comment: I don't think so. Macros aren't expanded when defining other macros. It expands all of them when the macro is used.

Comment: If you don't want a macro to be visible to the "user" then don't make it available to the user - define it in a private header, or directly in your private source(s) that use it. Because once it is made available, the "*user-code*" must be able to resolve it at compile time, and once the compiler can find it so is the user, no matter how hard you try to obfuscate it. In your example, if the "user" is allowed to see/use `ADD_ONE_TO`, then `SOME_MACRO` must also be defined somewhere otherwise the code won't compile.

Comment: Also, what do you actually want to do? This seems like an xy-problem. And why are you using macros in C++? On a side not, learn to use brackets liberally: like `@define SOME_MACRO(x,y) (x+y)`

Comment: @d4rk4ng31 I knew someone would say that. I'm just curious nothing more.

Answer (score 2):

When using GNU CPP you could use `#pragma GCC poison`, for example:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define print(...) printf(__VA_ARGS__)
#pragma GCC poison printf

int
main ()
{
        print("hi, %s", "there!"); /* Ok */
        printf("oh %s", "no!"); /* ERROR! use of poisoned keyword */
}
```

Tested and it works!

Comment: very interesting, is there any solution for visual studio compiler?

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not a standard feature. Only clang and GCC support it. Microsoft's Visual Studio has no equivalent feature. Sorry, didn't know you were using VS.